# TTFB 2+ seconds magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, server-setup

I am working with Cart2cart to import a large catalog of products. We have so far done a demo migration of 2 configurable products and about 2k simply products that are associated with them.

Before going ahead with the full import I noticed that the site was slow to load initially. I did some tests and found that the ttfb was the longest portion and consistently 2 seconds or a little more than 2 seconds. the total time to load the page for the first time according to tests is between 8 and 12 seconds.

I changed the magento mode to production mode, and that seems to have taken about 0.7 seconds off the ttfb (it was about 2.7 seconds before).

This is a very vanilla install of magento 2.1.5. The only customization has been the product import.

I uploaded a test txt file to check if it was the server and it loads instantly and has no ttfb for all test websites so it is not the server I don't think (I have asked the host as well and they told me it is not the server and that I can check using this txt method).

Another thing, after loading the webpage/product page for the first time reloading it is very fast, but still is 2 seconds for the TTFB.

Before going ahead with more customization and the full product catalog import I wanted to see if there was anything I can do to bring down that TTFB? I imagine after the database is much larger and the website is using a theme, with more addons things will only get much worse.

What else can I do?

Comment: there are lots of things to check, but , there is no information about your webstack.

Answer (score 2):

basically there are many things you can do without throwing more hardware in.

just to name some basics

- use php7
- use production mode
- use redis for session storage and backend cache
- use varnish for fullpage cache or if you cant use redis also

for cached pages we have a TTFB of 30 to 100 ms on staging system with 1 CPU and 2 GB RAM, althouth mostly less then 500 MB of RAM are utilized

but honestly even without redis and varnish 2 seconds seem really long.
do you already have any custom extensions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, Is PHP 7 stable with Magento 2? We are currently on 5.6.30. I switched to product mode and am still getting a 2-3 second ttfb. Our host is Nexcess and we are on the starting shared hosting plan SIP 100 which I believe is plenty powerful enough for such a basic setup. There are no custom extensions unless maybe the cart2cart import uses something I am unaware of. here is a link to my last test: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gostwear.nextmp.net/vL5LSusz

Comment: yes, magento2 supports php 7.0.x (not 7.1.x yet) and it gives a really huge performance boost for php. Still, when a page is cached, it should be faster. Basically I would say, that nexcess knows what they are doing, but if they did not recommend you to switch to php7, they consulted you really bad.

Comment: I will ask about 7.0, I can actually make the change myself from the nexcess admin panel but will confirm with them first. My initial request was for them to enable gzip which they did. I have varnish cache enabled in admin with TTL at 86400. Css and JSS minified and combined.

Comment: Switching to 7.0 seems to have given a pretty nice jump in page load time. TTFB is still pretty high at 0.9 seconds on the low size and 1.5 on the high now but on a whole a big improvement so thank you for recommending that. The person I have a ticket with said I can switch but that it would not have a big effect, which I think was incorrect it had a pretty large effect. He said that Magento 2 is still in a state of development and that we would basically have to live with the long ttfb until things improve in that regard.

Comment: Sorry to pile on, I'm not sure anyone will even read this lol but gtmetrix has been reporting the lack of gzip, so has google page insight. I know that it is enabled but it looks like certain files are not being gzipped for instance the minified JS is a big culprit. Is there anything that needs to be done to gzip the minified files?

Comment: Just me talking to myself, but the biggest problem was that I had varnish enabled in the full page cache options when I am on a shared server that could not have varnish enabled.  Turning on the regular page cache brought down the ttfb to 300 ms. A bunch of other little changes too brought down full load to just under 3 seconds, so very happy with that.

Comment: ah ok. Yes, having varnish enabled but no configured varnish server in place might lead to having no full page cache at all

Comment: @Sackling simplest solution to the gzip nonsense is to use a cdn. The changing static files index means you don't even have to flush it. Cloudfront also gives you http2 (no doubt others do also). I found this decreased my over all load times a lot.